# How do I ground my SFTP keystone without a patch panel

Tags: networking, ethernet, interference, twisted-pair

With the fiber optics being offered for my old small house [60m² build in 1990], I wanted to avoid using Wi-Fi and use an ethernet connection. The length between where the fiber outlet will be and my desk is 20 meters. I wanted to have cat5e Solid  UTP to avoid all this business about grounding, **plus I do not install the ethernet cable near the electrical cable**, but the seller refused to sell me cat5e for a custom length of 20 meters and only offered custom length for a cat6a U/FTP Solid  cable....

I also ordered 2 keystone jacks rated for SFTP and now I do not know how to ground all those things.
here is the simple explanation of my ''network''

optical outlet  [in the lounge]
=>ONT [in the lounge]
=>router given by the ISP  [in the lounge]
=>little patch cable cat5e [shielded?] [in the lounge]
=>female  rj45 outlet in the wall with SFTP keystone jacks [in the lounge]
=>U/FTP cat6a Solid  cable of length 20 meters  going into the attic  from the lounge to my office
=>female  rj45 outlet in the wall with SFTP keystone jacks [in the office]
=>little cat6a patch cable [shielded?]  [in my office]
=>my computer [laptop from 2019] [in my office]

As you see I do not have any patch panel with its cable being attached to whatever makes the ground in proper installations.

If I cannot ground those things, what can I do decrease the risk of interference (risk is small since my house is very small and I do not put the ethernet cable near big electrical devices)?

Can the router for end consumer by the ISP be grounded? If so, how do I check it is grounded?

if the router of the ISP is not grounded, can I put a device [a switch?] on my network which does the grounding?

Comment: I'm not sure but is grounding actually necessary to help with interference at all? Ethernet already uses differential signalling and AFAIK that's what already provides most of its resistance.

Comment: @ grawity, Differential signaling is resilient up to about 30mhz. The grounding improves on the total **Shannon Capacity**. https://www.cablinginstall.com/home/article/16467568/the-myths-and-realities-of-shielded-screened-cabling